# Big-theta: are (n-2)! and n! in different growth orders/efficiency classes?

Tags: limits, asymptotics, factorial

From what I've been taught, to compare the growth orders of two functions, $t(n)$ and $s(n)$, we find 
$$
lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{t(n)}{s(n)}
$$
where $n$ is the input size.

- If the limit is zero, then $s(n)$'s order of growth is greater than $t(n)$'s.
- If the limit is a constant, then $s(n)$ and $t(n)$ are in the same growth order/efficiency class.
- If the limit approaches infinity, then $t(n)$'s growth order is greater than greater than $s(n)$'s.

So for $(n-2)!$ vs $n!$ we have:
$$lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{(n-2)!}{n!} =lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{(n-2)!}{(n)(n-1)(n-2)!} = lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{1}{(n)(n-1)} = 0 $$

This seems very counter-intuitive, because at first glance I'd think that $(n-2)!$ would have the same growth order as $n!$. Did I go wrong somewhere, or is it actually in a growth order of its own?

Comment: Maybe your intuition has been thrown off by examples like $x^2 = O((x - 2)^2)$ and $2^x = O(2^{x - 2})$. With both of these what's happening is basically that the function doesn't get *that much* bigger (you can bound the factor increase by a constant) when you add in a constant to its argument, but when you add a constant to the argument of the factorial, the factorial gets a polynomial in $n$ times bigger, which is HUGE, and only gets bigger.

Comment: Yep, that absolutely explains why it seemed so intuitively wrong to me - didn't even think of those examples.